# Select columns information in interbase

Tags: interbase

I need to select all columns of my database and their properties
(default, comment, type, Precision, Scale, if primary Key, nullable and auto increment).

What command do I use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT rdb$field_name, rel_field.rdb$field_name,
    rdb$field_type, rdb$field_sub_type,
    rel_field.rdb$null_flag, rdb$field_length, rdb$field_scale,
    rdb$character_length, rdb$field_precision,
    field.rdb$default_source, field.rdb$validation_source
  FROM rdb$relations rel
    JOIN rdb$relation_fields rel_field
      ON rel_field.rdb$relation_name = rel.rdb$relation_name
    JOIN rdb$fields field
      ON rel_field.rdb$field_source = field.rdb$field_name
  WHERE rel.rdb$relation_name = : RelationName     <<---- insert tablename here
  ORDER BY rel_field.rdb$field_position, rel_field.rdb$field_name
```

See this page for more info:
http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/db/interbase/using_interbase_system_tables/using_interbase_system_tables.html